# Grails: mocking calls to other taglibs from within a taglib

Tags: grails, mocking, taglib

The grails application that I'm working on (using grails 2.2.1) has many low level taglibs to do things like creating links for certain domain objects.  There are other aggregate taglibs that combine calls to the lower level tabligs, such as building a list of these links.  The grails supported way of testing taglibs that reference other taglibs is to use "mockTagLib" within the test of the taglib that calls another, which basically creates an instance of the dependent taglig for the test and includes the real output of the dependent tag.  The end result of testing the aggregate taglib is that it is also testing the output of the dependent taglib.  This adds complexity to the unit tests (which is not really a unit test anymore) and is a mantainance issue if we ever want to change the output of the dependent taglibs, since changes would also break the aggregate tablib tests.  Is there a way to mock the interactions of a taglib with its dependent taglibs?  My team has done quite a bit of research and haven't been able to find any solutions with any of the popular grails mocking frameworks.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you can add your mocked taglib in the applicationContext. This is a static attribute that's available in unit tests.